# How can I use a global variable in another file in Python?

Tags: python

I want to make `i` into 3 in file s2.py, but it keeps becoming 1.

#### File *s1.py*

```
i=1

class a():
    def f():
        global i
        i = 3
```

#### File s2.py

```
from s1 import *

a.f()
print(i)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify variables in another python file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39425762/how-to-modify-variables-in-another-python-file)

Answer (score 1):

Every module has its own global scope, and Python is lexically scoped, meaning `a.f` refers to the global scope of `s1` no matter where it is called from. `i` is *initialized* to the value of `s1.i`, but is otherwise independent of it. Changes to `s1.i` do not affect `s2.i`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referencing the local variable `i` and aren't referencing the instance of `i` in the class. Try this.

```
print(a.i)
```

Comment: There isn't any instance of `i` in the class. Calling `print(a.i)` will throw an error. There are only two instances if `i`, one in `s1` and one in `s2` (created using `from s1 import *`).

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-import your variable after calling your method if you want to see any changes made.

```
#s1.py
i=1

class a():
    def f():
        global i
        i = 3

#s2.py
from s1 import *    
a.f()

from s1 import i
print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#s1.py
i=1

class a():
    def f():
        global i
        i += 3



#s2.py
import s1

s1.a.f()
print(s1.i)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Reimport the variable after calling the method:

#### File *s1.py*

```
i = 1

class a():
    def f():
        global i
        i += 3
```

#### File *s2.py*

```
import s1

s1.a.f()
print(s1.i)
```